# Aligning two 50% divs with margin and without overflow

Tags: css, html

how do I have two divs with 50% width side by side and a margin without the second div dropping underneath the first?
Div id style is as follows:

```
#div3{width:50%; float:left; margin: 2px; background-color:yellow;}
```

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: you can't. 50% + 50% = 100% and anything more is greater than 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#div3{width:48%; float:left; margin: 1%; background-color:yellow;}
```

hows that?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I have tried altering the margin percentage as per Owen's example. Works great. Thank you. Pity there is no way to make an inner margin which keeps the 100% aspect but separates the columns easily into grids.

Comment: There's a different way about this. check out `box-sizing: border-box` in CSS. Then you could use padding inside the divs, instead of margin outside. Watch out for browser support though.

Answer (score 3):

50% + 50% + margins **>** 100%

Therefore, the elements wrap. You will need to adjust the width or the margins to stay within the 100% limit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the width of divs to less than 50% because together they have 50% + 50% + 4x margin 2px. Try to change it to an exact value in pixels or f.e. 49%.

Answer (score 1):

The margin will give extra width to the div elements.
You could try setting the divs to 49% each and giving each div a margin auto.

This will centralise the divs and still give you a small amount of margin dependant on the browsers size.

Answer (score 0):

I always cheated and set them both at 49% width, and then added padding (not a margin). But you want some visual colorblocking, right? If you want one to have a background and one to be no background (relative to the rest of the page) set the yellow one at 50%, and the no-color background one at 49%.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the new `box-sizing` property which subtracts the padding from the width instead of adding it on top like you are experiencing:

```
div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Most browsers don't support the entire spec yet but it can accomplish what you want: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing.

Though I believe that you would have to use padding instead of margin to create the spacing.